# Implementing a generic function with a conditional return type

Tags: typescript

I'm trying a very basic (contrived) conditional type function and getting unexpected errors:

```
function test<
  T
>(
  maybeNumber: T
): T extends number ? number : string {
  if (typeof maybeNumber === 'number') {
    return maybeNumber // Type 'T & number' is not assignable to type 'T extends number ? number : string'.
  }

  return 'Not a number' // Type '"Not a number"' is not assignable to type 'T extends number ? number : string'.
}
```

I thought that this was a pretty straightforward usage of a conditional type so not sure what's going on. Any ideas?

To clarify, I’m not really trying to implement this specific function. I’m just experimenting with conditional types and want to better understand why this doesn’t actually work.

Comment: There are a number of answers here already, but I wanted to make sure to link to [microsoft/TypeScript#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912), a GitHub issue talking specifically about conditional type assignability failures in generic functions.  That might be a good place to start for the answer to "why this doesn't work".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The underlying issue is that TypeScript's compiler does not narrow the type of a generic type variable via control flow analysis.  When you check `(typeof maybeNumber === "number")`, the compiler can narrow the *value* `maybeNumber` to `number`, but it does not narrow the *type parameter* `T` to `number`.  And therefore it cannot verify that it's safe to assign a `number` value to the return type `T extends number ? number : string`.  The compiler would have to perform some analysis it currently does not do, such as "okay, if `typeof maybeNumber === "number"`, and we inferred `T` from the type of `maybeNumber` alone, then inside this block we can narrow `T` to `number`, and therefore we should return a value of type `number extends number ? number : string`, a.k.a., `number`".  But this doesn't happen.

This is quite a pain point with generic functions with conditional return types.  The canonical open GitHub issue about this is probably [microsoft/TypeScript#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912), but there are a bunch of other GitHub issues out there where this is the main problem.

So that's the answer to "why doesn't this work"?

---

If you're not interested in refactoring to get this to work, you can ignore the rest, but it might still be instructive to know what to do in this situation instead of waiting for the language to change.

The most straightforward workaround here that maintains your call signature is to make your function a single signature [overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) where the implementation signature is not generic.  This essentially loosens the type safety guarantees inside the implementation:

```
type MyConditional<T> = T extends number ? number : string;
type Unknown = string | number | boolean | {} | null | undefined;

function test<T>(maybeNumber: T): MyConditional<T>;
function test(maybeNumber: Unknown): MyConditional<Unknown> {
  if (typeof maybeNumber === 'number') {
    const ret: MyConditional<typeof maybeNumber> = maybeNumber;
    return ret;
  }
  const ret: MyConditional<typeof maybeNumber> = "Not a number";
  return ret;
}
```

Here I've gone about as far as I can go to try to guarantee type safety, by using a temporary `ret` variable annotated as `MyConditional<typeof maybeNumber>` which uses the control-flow-analysis-narrowed type of `maybeNumber`.  This will at least complain if you switch around the check (turn `===` into `!==` to verify).  But usually I just do something simpler like this and let the chips fall where they may:

```
function test2<T>(maybeNumber: T): MyConditional<T>;
function test2(maybeNumber: any): string | number {
  if (typeof maybeNumber === 'number') {
    return maybeNumber;
  }
  return "Not a number";
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiDCB7AdgEwJbHSghgGwB4AVAPigF4oioIAPYCNAZymQFcBbAIwgCcoA-K049+ALihNgvdMgDmAbgBQoSFACqyANbJEAd2QVJ02XKgAfYdz4WoXRIjwQchywG8AvrfZ48ttmgQAGayEKjKSkEBAMZYKFAMUsQkABQcOCA8AHIifBJEAJQScEhomNjI+MnKUcixFQkQUmkZ2bm8Epo6+shFsAgoGHGVhF26BmRuSlBQ6EFQKaoQiPPpmRA51vzkO1AA5OxbewVQUzMz0ShSULwQwMUDZcNVSytQa21bZJQfG+3K5xudzYvEMt2AAKgHmmUEuyGu4IepSGFRe4GWq1afy+RgARFlEMAoDgrKJcZDwSCwXdlNDIjFho0pAAmZItdabUT5PolQblXCEUg1BkNRLAZnsz5c4nIEB9KQyeTedqnGFzBavTEclU7SgHdrHVWAymg95Yzl8SHQmYmwz4wnE0l8clKa1AA)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, but for the first way doesn't work, I have `type ConditionalType<T> = T extends 'fields' ? {key: boolean} : boolean;`, but if I return `{key: true}` if `key === 'fields'`, it says `Type '{ key: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.`, what do I do wrong ?

Comment: @Ayfri Please check [this code](https://tsplay.dev/WoqxgN), which works.  Notice that I'm using a single overload, as mentioned in this answer.  If something doesn't work for you about this solution, please try to produce a [mcve] that I or someone else could use to see what you're talking about.

Comment: Very nice answer, I didn't know that there was a use case for an overload with one additional call signature. Weird that TS docs state so strongly that: "The signature of the *implementation* is not visible from the outside. When writing an overloaded function, **you should always have *two* or more signatures above the implementation of the function**."

Answer (score 3):

Correct answer and current workaround (at the time of writing):

```
type MaybeNumberType<T extends number | string> = T extends number
  ? number
  : string;

function test<T extends number | string>(
  maybeNumber: T,
): MaybeNumberType<T> {
  if (typeof maybeNumber === 'number') {
    return <MaybeNumberType<T>>(<unknown>maybeNumber);
  }

  return <MaybeNumberType<T>>(<unknown>'Not a number');
}

test(3); // 3
test('s'); // Not a number
```

Answer (score 2):

Your function would be better off if implemented with overloads:

```
function test(arg: number): number;
function test(arg: unknown): string;
function test(arg: any): string | number {
  if (typeof arg === 'number') {
    return arg;
  }

  return 'Not a number'
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I’m not really looking for a different way to implement. More just wanting to understand conditional types. I’ve amended my question to clarify

Comment: This is not a great solution as the conditional type may have many different return types and may be used in different places. Using method overloads results in a much less maintainable source base and definitely not as flexible. While technically a work around, it is not a realistic solution for the issue

Answer (score 0):

I believe you were defining the return type in the wrong place:

```
function test<T extends number | String>(maybeNumber: T) {
if (typeof maybeNumber === 'number') {
  return maybeNumber
}
return 'Not a number'
```

}

Comment: So that's not quite the same. My intent was to take any type (not just number or string). My goal is to have a conditional return type such that the compiler can infer the result type based on the input type. I think in your example the return type will always be inferred as number | string regardless of input type.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `maybeNumber` can be a number at runtime even when `T` does not extend `number`. In that case, your function returns a `number` but its type declaration says it should return `string`. Consider:

```js
function test_the_test(value: Object) {
    // no type error here, even though test(value) will return a number at runtime
    let s: string = test(value);
}

test_the_test(23);
```

In this case, `T = Object`, which does not extend `number` - it is a supertype, not a subtype - so the conditional type `T extends number ? number : string` resolves to `string`. We can test this with a generic type:

```js
type Test<T> = T extends number ? number : string
type TestObject = Test<Object>
// TestObject is string
```

So, your function `test` actually returns a number in at least one case where it claims it will return a string. That means the function is not type-safe, and it's correct that you get a type error.

In fact, there is no sensible, type-safe implementation of your function given these type annotations. `test<number>(23)` should return `number`, but `test<Object>(23)` should return `string`; yet both compile to the same Javascript, so there is no way to know at runtime which type the function is expected to return. The only way to satisfy both constraints is to write a function which never returns (e.g. by unconditionally throwing an exception); if you never return a value, the return value can never have the wrong type. So your function needs to be redesigned.

---

There are two sensible ways in Typescript to write a function which checks that the input is a number. One is to write a [user-defined type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) which narrows the type of its argument to `number` if it returns `true`:

```js
function isNumber(x: any): x is number {
    return typeof x === 'number';
}
```

The other is to write an [assertion function](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) which narrows the type of its argument to `number` by throwing an error if it's not a number:

```js
function assertNumber(x: any): asserts x is number {
    if(typeof x !== 'number') {
        throw new TypeError('Not a number');
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, neither of these returns a string when the input is not a number. But either might be adapted for your actual use case.

Comment: So does that imply that you can’t use a conditional return type based on an input type since it could similarly be a supertype?

Comment: "`T = number | string`"  No it's not, because control flow analysis narrows the type of `value` to `number`, so `T` is actually `number` here.  Even if that were true:  "the conditional type `T extends number ? number : string` resolves to `string`"  No it doesn't, because it [distributes over unions in `T`](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types).  I don't think this paragraph should stay  Possibly you can salvage it by using `unknown` instead of `string | number` but many distributive conditionals act weird with `unknown`.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for pointing that out. I've edited to use `Object` as the supertype instead of `number | string`, to avoid the problem with using a union type.

Comment: @bingles I don't think it implies you can never use a conditional type as the return type of a function in a typesafe way - just that it is possible to use one in a way that can't be implemented safely without unconditionally throwing an exception. It's likewise impossible for a function like `function foo<S, T>(x: S): T { /* ... */ }` which claims to return an arbitrary type `T` with no access to `T` at runtime, but that doesn't mean you can never use generic return types.