# Valid resolved type of a Typescript conditional type is not permitted mapping back to the conditional type

Tags: typescript

I'm wondering before reporting a bug if there is a way to do this. Here is a stackblitz of the issue:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-wdvejf?file=index.ts

In the hypothetical example below, the conditional type is either `Business` or `Person` based on an enumeration value passed in (in this example a key for a map and a function parameter). Typescript is correctly casting the use of `AddressBookEntryType.Business` to an instance of `Business` but even though `Business` is a type of `AddressBookEntry`, the `Business` value cannot be returned from the function without a hack (forced casting).

Here is the conditional type:

```
type AddressBookEntry<T> = T extends AddressBookEntryType.Business
  ? Business
  : T extends AddressBookEntryType.Person
  ? Person
  : never;
```

And the function:

```
const addressBookMap: Map<
  AddressBookEntryType,
  Map<string, AddressBookEntry<any>>
> = new Map();

const getFromMap = <T extends AddressBookEntryType>(
  key: string,
  entryType: T
): AddressBookEntry<T> => {
  const byTypeMap = addressBookMap.get(entryType);
  if (byTypeMap !== null) {
    return byTypeMap.get(key); // <-- compiler error
  } else {
    return null;
  }
};
```

The error:

```
Type 'Business | Person' is not assignable to type 'AddressBookEntry<T>'.
  Type 'Business' is not assignable to type 'AddressBookEntry<T>'.(2322)
```

The rest of the code:

```
interface Business {
  name: string;
}

interface Person {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
}

// Now define an enumeration for what types may be stored in the address book:

enum AddressBookEntryType {
  Person,
  Business
}
```

Work-around/hack 1 is to define the conditional type as `any`:

```
type AddressBookEntry<T> = T extends AddressBookEntryType.Business
  ? Business
  : T extends AddressBookEntryType.Person
  ? Person
  : any; // <-- should be never here as there are no other valid options instead of any
```

This is not ideal as it makes it seem that there are other options besides the 2 valid types.

Work-around/hack 2 is to cast the result:

```
const getFromMap = <T extends AddressBookEntryType>(
  key: string,
  entryType: T
): AddressBookEntry<T> => {
  const byTypeMap = addressBookMap.get(entryType);
  if (byTypeMap !== null) {
    return byTypeMap.get(key) as AddressBookEntry<T>;
  } else {
    return null;
  }
};
```

Is there a way to do this without a cast, work-around or a hack and keep it "pure"?

Comment: This is another duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59904247/typescript-conditional-type-unexpected-errors).  The canonical answer is unfortunately "no, you can't do this".  See [microsoft/TypeScript#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912) for the general issue.

Answer (score 1):

This issue seems to capture what I am seeing.

Thanks @jcalz

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912