# Make return type value if generic string argument is a literal string but other if not

Tags: typescript, generics, types, string-literals, conditional-types

I have a situation a bit complicated, I have an interface `Options` with some keys & values.
I want to make a function that has a single argument that should be only `keyof Options`, but the return type should be different if the argument is `fields`, it should return an object, otherwise, it should return a boolean. But my tests are not successful :/

My test :

```js
interface Options {
    fields: string;
    someOtherKeys: number;
    someOtherKeys2: number;
    // ...
}

function myFunction<K extends keyof Options(key: K): K extends "fields" ? {key: boolean} : boolean {
    if (key === 'fields') return {key: true};
    else return false;
}
// This is a simplified test, not my real code.
```

I'm getting weirds errors on the code like:
For the first line: `Type '{ key: true; }' is not assignable to type 'K extends "fields" ? { key: boolean; } : boolean'.`
For the second: `Type 'false' is not assignable to type 'K extends "fields" ? { key: boolean; } : boolean'.`

Comment: See the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59905652/2887218) to the question this duplicates.  Translating that answer to this question yields [this code](https://tsplay.dev/mMy7lm).

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't _really_ work :/