# How to Implement an interface with conditional types in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

On a personal project I am facing an issue with TypeScript conditional types. I have basic understanding of conditional types from the TypeScript docs. I would expect the setup below to work but it gives a type error.

Basicaly I am trying to define an interface for a tree node which is loaded from the disk. This means that some of the nodes may not be correctly loaded because of missing files etc. So any node implementation either contains `Content` or `Error`.

```
interface Content {
  data: number;
}

interface Error {
  code: string;
}

export interface TreeNode<T extends Content | Error> {
  getValue(): T extends Content ? number : string;
}

class ValueNode<ValueType extends Content> implements TreeNode<ValueType> {
  private readonly value: number;
  public constructor(value: number) {
    this.value = value;
  }
 
  public getValue(): number {
    return this.value;
  }
}
```

I would expect that the implementation of the `getValue` method would be allowed to return `string` since the interface is implemented with type extending `Content`. But I get this type error intead:

> - Property `getValue` in type `ValueNode<ValueType>` is not assignable to the same property in base type `TreeNode<ValueType>`.
>
>   - Type `() => number` is not assignable to type `() => ValueType extends Content ? number : string`.
>
>     - Type `number` is not assignable to type `ValueType extends Content ? number : string`

Cleary, I am doing it the wrong way. What would be the correct way to achieve my goal?

Comment: Given that `ValueType` is a type-parameter, why aren't you using it at all inside `ValueNode<...>`?

Comment: BTW, `Error` is a built-in type, so you should give your `interface Error` a distinct name, like `interface MyError` or so.

Comment: Typescript is great for making JavaScript into c#. And, that can be useful with node. JavaScript doesn't have ["types"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures) in the same way. @dai edited the error to make it more transparent.

Comment: @wahwahwah Pardon? None of what you said has any relevance to the problem at-hand.

Comment: OP, have you read this QA? I think it's relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59904247/implementing-a-generic-function-with-a-conditional-return-type

Comment: Looks like `class ValueNode implements TreeNode<Content>` is what you're looking for..

Comment: FWIW, provided that implementations of `TreeNode<T>` are non-parametric (i.e. non-generic) themselves then things work fine. I have a TS Playground example, but I can't share it because of the stupid SO Comment Link length restriction, argh.

Comment: @Dai You can use tsplay.dev if you are ok with a third-party shortener.

Comment: @wahwahwah Although they have a common pedigree, TypeScript is as far removed from C# as JavaScript is.

Comment: @AluanHaddad - maybe I should have been clearer... the syntactic sugar in TypeScript resembles C# , but the underlying *types* are javascript types. If the OP were to look at what TypeScript is *actually* doing it might become clearer why the error is being thrown.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. However, with the exception of the `enum` and rarely used `namespace` constructs, all of the sugar you are talking about is already part of JavaScript

Answer (score 2):

> As @Dai [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70316178/how-to-implement-an-interface-with-conditional-types-in-typescript#comment124299309_70316178), it's better not to [shadow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the built-in `Error` type (so that you can use it in your module).

Here are two alternatives:

[TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=28&pc=2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIHtwXANTgGwFcUBvAWAChlkATOMOALmREIFsAjaAbkoF9KlUJFiIUAUShR0UPEVKVqCdDQjMAzmCigA5rwoCKlCAA8ADjLDJh0eEmRziAcQhgRAHgAqAPmTkqyDqujhAAFACUzJ76hpQI+HDq6g4ExAByKhBeyKaQIDTJGFi4qRC+wGxm+BBs2GDJIS5u0O5FeWAhANoA5HQM3QC6vv7UZoQc+MAIyMogmlCECGAyoWbaAG70KFAQcDSY+ACeyJvyUeF+hsiKyGMTU4HBpRHMrJzQfjfUO2CEUCDIMAAC2A6gAdKdiGC+nB9NRDLEKAB6JHIGRxBJJZAAZQqVQgIQyqmyuWwBTQmHaIWGNzuk2ms3mi2WUFWGy2yB2ewOx0hamQnguJCutPG9MeHWekRY7C4UE+AW+rj+AOBoIhpWh9FhNwRlCAA)

```ts
interface ContentValue {
  data: number;
}

interface ErrorValue {
  code: string;
}

export interface ValueGetter<T> {
  getValue(): T;
}

class ValueNode<T extends ContentValue> implements ValueGetter<ContentValue['data']> {
  public constructor(private readonly value: T) {}
 
  public getValue(): number {
    return this.value.data;
  }
}

// or
class SimpleValueNode<T extends ContentValue> {
  public constructor(private readonly value: T) {}
 
  public getValue(): number {
    return this.value.data;
  }
}
```

Comment: I think the OP still intends for `ValueNode` to be an _open_ generic type though...

Comment: @Dai You mean like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NVgD7m)?

Comment: Almost, but your `class ValueNode` needs to constrain `T` to `ContentValue` and disallow `ErrorValue`.

Comment: @jsejcksn Yes! I have a typo in the original question. The `value` inside `TreeNode` should be generic. Your example works and makes sense. But I don't understand why is does not work, when it looks like [this](https://gist.github.com/podlomar/49c72434c5ed6c4fea1cfb84644beb64)

Comment: @lishaak I've updated my answer. (It's not clear to me why the `TreeNode` interface is needed if the single method implementation is going to be annotated anyway.) Do one of those variations work for you?