# Writing a strongly typed generic normalize function in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm trying to write a strongly typed generic function in TypeScript that essentially trims all the strings it can find at any depth within an object and leaves anything that is not a string unchanged while preserving the type of the input argument, something whose minimal version would be:

```js
export const normalize = <T>(x: T): T => {
  if (typeof x === 'string') {
    return x.trim();
  }

  return x;
};
```

But I'm getting the error:

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T'.
  'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'string'.ts(2322)
```

I wrote a [fiddle](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM72dAtgQwDYCWAXsHALxwA8AKgHwAUIAXHNQJQvXm1wDeAsACg4cAgDM49GAE8wwCBJDkyFAOTooBZAHNVbPkJEiowGAFcoyOCAB0MTVnpsA3IbgBfIW5PnL114LuzkA) for this.

I do not understand: shouldn't TS infer from the `typeof x === 'string'` guard that T is a string?

**Edit**: as pointed out by @VLAZ in the comments, it actually makes sense, because several things could have type string and somebody could call the function with `normalize<'foo   '>('hello')` which doesn't make sense. I'm trying another approach where I'm explicit about the input types I allow, but I'm having [issues with the "object"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAcg9gJwLYEMA2BLAXigRm6AXgFgAoKKAOwFclcIEoAfMigZ2AQ0oHNnXYiVJhz4IAbQC6-clADeUcQGsIIAFxQOXXpI3xk6bHgJQAvgG4yZAPQAqW61uCDI6CkpQ4uAFYQAxsBQCP7UCGwYAG4QaCAANI5QnBhISNx8wAAW0AQoACZpUO65iQgoGJi8UADuGRjAEGxgKH7QcABmhWhomkm8bAB0jtZkEAAeYIiBfnCUHFRChlhEUAAUo3oLIsYQAJQbLkZiUIQAfPICGB0roJDtUKPHhIRQAORaaS8757IUwcChHlG-SSSBWO0sslMVlkl1WAEEEKUQP0MGwEUi1jsvnIBL8IP8EID%20qgwCtKJtsLsIRQoaQLlcHgAyRmJcAQO4PJ7PF5eXwBT7fCgUaazQLBXLUFqMZ4AHlxQoA8lAxvVKLk2M5hIcTCyFMpVBp3jp9lrRCZTPEfkKANLK0aq9VQFQgO4Ky1CqAnFbNPwaN2KZ2xKARdDUCC6RTWoMK8TWySSPaaxbbY5nHFWig%20-UgaTPckHJYrENoMPg%20V4gkeH3UoUWaEev4AqAKnz%20YD9CCUJINTH9cWSiArftSoNyUxlyH1oL4pujCEWIA) case.

**Edit 2**: Well I came up with [a solution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAcg9gJwLYEMA2BLAXigRm6AXgFgAoKKAOwFclcIEoAfMigZ2AQ0oHNnXYiVJhz4IAbQC6-clADeUcQGsIIAFxQOXXpI3xk6bHgJQAvgG4yZAPQAqW61uCDI6CkpQ4uAFYQAxsBQCP7UCGwYAG4QaCAANI5QnBhISNx8wAAW0AQoACZpUO65iQgoGJi8UADuGRjAEGxgKH7QcABmhWhomkm8bAB0jtZkEAAeYIiBfnCUHFRChlhEUAAUo3oLIsYQAJQbLkZiUIQAfPICGB0roJDtUKPHhIRQAORaaS8757IUwcChHlG-SSSBWO0sslMVlkl1WAEEEKUQP0MGwEUi1jsvnIBL8IP8EID+qgwCtKJtsLsIRQoaQLlcbhA7g8ns8Xl5fAFPt8KBRprNAhBKEkGscoAB5Hz+YD9IUitiY6m8-lzYJsahoYD7YSHEzPOQWXFQOVcBr9NqIACizQyKxWylUsSgEXQ1Agki+px5vLx6s1DpA0me5IOSxWLrQbvBRtM0Z+QXxAITfuAStpAj+SdGEMNpCAA) that provides some type safety but it's still not preserving the input type.

Comment: Example where the code would be incorrect: `normalize<"foo">(someString)` - remember that *the caller* determines `T` and there is nothing stopping them from having a more specific thing than just `string`.

Comment: thx, now I understand, any idea how I would go about typing such a function?

Comment: Could you do something like `return x.trim() as unknown as T;`?

Comment: Are you looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70330904/process-for-a-specific-type-else-return-same-value-in-typescript#answer-70332643) ?

Comment: If you call `trim` on argument it is very unsafe to return same generic type `T`. See [example](https://tsplay.dev/wg6RvW)

Comment: yeah I think I'm gonna go with providing the explicit input types I'm allowing, but now I'm having diffuculties with the Object case, I've added a new fiddle

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/NaYPnN) meet your needs?  It looks like you don't care about preserving string literal types (you don't need the *type* of `normalize("  abc  ")` to be `"abc"`; you're fine with `string`) but you do care about preserving the shape of your input type as long as any string literal types become  `string`.  I can write this up as an answer if it works for you; if not, please [edit] to show any unsatisfied use cases.  (Also, please include your link-only code as plaintext as well; right now the plaintext code in your question does not look at nesting.)

Comment: @jcalz your function is loosing a bit more type information than I'd like to but yes I believe that would indeed work for me, at least way better than what I have now thx!

Comment: "your function is losing a bit more type information than I'd like to" How so?  I mean, I guess you say it doesn't matter so I can write up an answer anyway, but I want to understand the issue.

Comment: Well as you said it's preserving the shape of the input, which is great, but it loses the, how is it called? Type constructor name?

E.g. if you have a class `A` with just a single property `x: string` then `normalize(new A)` will be of type `{ x: string }` and no longer of type `A`.

I do not foresee any immediate issues with that, but I don't have enough knowledge to realize in which cases that may be a problem.