# How to type for an optional transform

Tags: typescript

I think code is the best way to explain what I'm trying to do:

```
interface Input { in: string }
interface Output { out: string }

function doStuff(input: Input): Output {
    return { out: input.in };
}

function f<Out>(input: Input, transform?: (data: Output) => Out) /* result-type ? */ {
    const output = doStuff(input);
    if(transform) return transform(output);
    else return output;
}
f({in: 'simple'}).out == 'simple';
f({in: 'with transform'}, (data: Output) => data.out) == 'with transform';
```

I'm struggling to get the return type of the function `f` right. Basically I want `f` to return `Output` when `transform` is undefined and the result type of `transform` when it is given.

I tried using different declarations for both cases, and conditional types, but there always is some issue. Can this be modeled with typescript ?

Comment: Overloads would be simpler here

Answer (score 2):

> I tried using different declarations for both cases, and conditional types, but there always is some issue. Can this be modeled with typescript?

By "different declarations", I presume that you mean [function overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) ([which work for your case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71469336/438273)).

This cannot currently be modeled using conditional types, because TypeScript is not yet capable of [inferring type information from optional parameters which are constrained generics](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14400). But if it could, your conditional version would look something like this (*doesn't work!*):

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgTgQwHYGcBmB7OBbAPASQBooB5APigF4oAKAEwWAQC4p8BKKikgbgFgAUKEhskYAK7BcMCtQDeUAJZJWMKAF9+Q8NBKSJUmVSgKMk1Rq2C04pAGNgijEih0MAZWDi0aKNLI0ygas+GKS-uysesAG-iaCUFBwEF5wLqbmSmHAAHTKloLqgta2Dk4uvtLEAGIuEAAewBBIdCiwiKiYOLjRsTLEyCBkAQlZwaJ9ZISjObMA2sAd6FjYALqsc6tQAD5QC0td2Ky1q4KRUMIQGL6LyMs4UA1NLW22dBBoyhB0UAD8pPpwkZWAAlFLiNIwHS4WoUOSjOzOFDAKBmGKSYxuTzeNCBbLsLSJZKpFy3TorP4XA4rGhogycVh0yRaIoCaw0OTKVgAchQimwYAANhBuep2Dk0VRKNRefyhSKeFAAPRKqCDWjKRFwZIOQUgLJoCDa75QNBwDDYC4AC2gAHNmkbFHYoIjULdlMB2OzOSooNyAO6KYBWql3Q6i4gMJhcVyMBASyScaUywPB0PknDcxUqqDIuDKW20LU64B6g1G5J0L0CIA)

```ts
type Transform<I, O> = (data: I) => O;
type Input<T> = { in: T };
type Output<T> = { out: T };

function doStuff <T>(input: Input<T>): Output<T> {
  return { out: input.in };
}

function f <T, Fn extends Transform<Output<T>, any>>(
  input: Input<T>,
  ...[transform]: [] | [transform: Fn]
): typeof transform extends undefined ? Output<T> : ReturnType<Fn> {
  const output = doStuff(input);
  return transform ? transform(output) : output;
}

f({in: 'simple'}).out === 'simple'; // any (incorrectly inferred from the generic constraint)
f({in: 'with transform'}, data => data.out) === 'with transform'; // string (correctly inferred)
```

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59905652/438273

Answer (score 1):

Two overloads do the trick:

```
function f(input: Input): Output;
function f<T extends (data: Output) => unknown>(input: Input, transform: T): ReturnType<T>;
function f<T extends ((data: Output) => unknown) | undefined>(input: Input, transform?: T)  {
    const output = doStuff(input);
    if(transform) return transform(output);
    else return output;
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIgA4FczIN7KgBcyAzmFKAObIC+AsAFCiSyIoDyO2uBA9jhLlKIGg0ZMYWEAjDA+IZABM+AZTBYYMABSgeJdDwCUJLmB74mya8igQNURf0GFMOAHSg6AbibjJ0rLyijp6LoY4JshmPL6MUjJyCsgwADwAKsgQAB6QIEqkyNpKcGBwptyRyAC8AHzI0gDWIHwA7iC1um5gBt0ANMgUcCCkMHxQALYk6VEASvZYjukAnhgQGbVxCUHJaZk5eQVFxaXl0ZVgRjX1TS3tVwA+DfkQMKAQSp1hPWj9g1DDUbjCYAfmmV0sjBsyAQCnIyAE5hwNWUag0Wi6xji0OAOiGIzGkyudgcinxQMm2kRWKsNggABtSCgSYtFNScHF-PFtHhiMgAOSkYATDD0iD82hGdyImrVAVCkVi-lbHl8-mtYBgAAW-0BhImEoGJzKFSRl2uylO0qq1Tl6s1OvJ+uVQA)

Comment: I had a variation of this at some point, but this doesn't work: `function g<T extends (data: Output) => unknown>(input: Input, transform?: T) { return f(input, transform) }`. I can work around that using a conditional but it's not ideal.