# Typescript: How do I properly use this conditional return type in my function?

Tags: typescript

The goal of the `makeRequest` function is

- If a `FooRequest` is passed in, return `Foo`
- If a `BarRequest` is passed in, return `Bar`
- If a `DurRequest` is passed in, return `Dur`

I created a `ConditionalOutput` generic type which does the mapping from a given request type to the return type. But I'm having issues getting TS to understand the logic of the function, it complains with `Type '{ t: "foo"; }' is not assignable to type 'ConditionalOutput<T>'`

[TypeScript Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nAShAjgVwgZ2FAvFAbwCgpSoB9YAQwHMAuKAcgDMFGAaEsgSwBMHsAJ24A7GpwC%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%20kMyYgqcE6c6k7GzVzMwLciLC5u3XLlfeNbrUAbTZbbZqb1ajG7TphboHnuHo7I44To0Y09n88zr5zebXCeLtyjDuEhVvu9aYI2zZUK27bnoWV6qn27q6veI5aFIYTfCILj-C4%20CatqBJmtU4a6FmHDvPwTAAIwAEwAMy9DapRAA)

```
type FooRequest = {
    _tag: 'foo',
    id: string,
}

type BarRequest = {
    _tag: 'bar',
    id: string,
}

type DurRequest = {
    _tag: 'dur',
    id: string,
}

type AllRequests = FooRequest | BarRequest | DurRequest;

type Foo = { t: 'foo' };
type Bar = { t: 'bar' };
type Dur = { t: 'dur' };


// chained conditional type mapping each "request" type to it's counterpart
type ConditionalOutput<T extends AllRequests> = 
    T extends FooRequest ? Foo : 
    T extends BarRequest ? Bar : 
    T extends DurRequest ? Dur : never;


function makeRequest<T extends AllRequests>(input: T) : ConditionalOutput<T> {
    switch (input._tag) {
        case 'foo': return { t: 'foo' }; // Type '{ t: "foo"; }' is not assignable to type 'ConditionalOutput<T>'.
        case 'bar': return { t: 'bar' }; // Type '{ t: "bar"; }' is not assignable to type 'ConditionalOutput<T>'.
        case 'dur': return { t: 'dur' }; // Type '{ t: "dur"; }' is not assignable to type 'ConditionalOutput<T>'.
    }
}

const test = makeRequest({ _tag: 'foo', id: '123' }); // it does properly give the variable `test` the type of `Foo`
```

Comment: You could [derive the output type from the input type without conditionals](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nAShAjgVwgZ2FAvFAbwCgooB9YAQwHMAuKAcgDMEGAaEqASwBN7sATlwB21DgF8iRUJCgAhSgOTosOfMVIUa9BgCNF7Tr37AhoiVJnQAImiWoM2PIU5a6jHncOljUQSLEiSWlwaABBABsI5UdgTGd4JAdVKAAfeUUYlPTbexVsAG5LUKgADQAeABUoCAAPYAhhHnjI6OTsTAA+ZwIoYHpKgG0AIjdhgF0oYKsoAE1cCsSs7E6gA)

Comment: All you need a cast like : `case 'foo': return { t: 'foo' } as ConditionalOutput<T>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59904247/implementing-a-generic-function-with-a-conditional-return-type

Comment: @spender that's handy, but what if the return type isn't something that isn't so easily created using a value from the parent type, such as these Foo,Bar and Bur types? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nAShAjgVwgZ2FAvFAbwCgooB9YAQwHMAuKAcgDMEGAaEqASwBN7sATlwB21DgF8iRUJCgAhSgOTosOfMVIUa9BgCNF7Tr37AhoiVJnQAImiWoM2PIU5a6jHncOljUQSLEiSUtwaHg4ZwIoYB0WOHYoGgh6YTQAW10IAShxAG5pUPlFSOidfQEE4Uo05L9TAJz8qyhbbPVSjy82KB5KYFrrPug8qQLZAEEAG0nlR2BMZ3DZ1SgAHyL7FSd11uXsfLHoAA0AHgAVKAgAD37hHgWpmYdVTAA+EpioM4BtACI3X4AXRyIVkAE1cKcls9sK8gA