# Typed reduce function

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I want to bring up a typed version of the reduce function with an optional accumulator argument. I've managed to do it by using type assertion, which I want to avoid:

```
type IF_UNDEFINED<A, T> = A extends undefined ? T : A;

export function reduce<T, A>(
  values: T[],
  callback: (prev: A, current: T) => A,
  accumulator: A
): A;
export function reduce<T>(
  values: T[],
  callback: (prev: T, current: T) => T,
  accumulator?: undefined
): T;

export function reduce<T, A>(
  values: T[],
  callback: (value1: IF_UNDEFINED<A, T>, value2: T) => IF_UNDEFINED<A, T>,
  accumulator?: A
): IF_UNDEFINED<A, T> {
  let currentValue = (
    accumulator !== undefined ? accumulator : values[0]
  ) as IF_UNDEFINED<A, T>;
  let nextValue: T;

  for (let i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
    nextValue = values[i];
    currentValue = callback(currentValue, nextValue);
  }

  return currentValue;
}
```

If I remove the assertion for currentValue it says Type 'T | (A & ({} | null))' is not assignable to type 'IF_UNDEFINED<A, T>'. I have no clue, why TS comes up with (A & ({} | null)) instead of just A. Can somebody explain what I am missing?

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-iEgRtaY5qydfNoQOicXsxeypYgpAzddyhYAvq7XsAMiYa5nhkoW0A)

Thousand thanks.

Comment: Type issues aside, can you give examples of how you expect to use the two different versions of the function? The use case is not clear, and it might help find a better design that does what you want and type checks.

Comment: Conditional return types are currently pretty limited in my understanding. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59904247/implementing-a-generic-function-with-a-conditional-return-type and the linked GitHub issues for some useful info.

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24929 which was closed in favor of https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014 also might be relevant reading.

Comment: Small suggestion, don't mutate values if you are using TypeScript, at least try to avoid mutations in such simple cases. TypeScript does not like mutations. See [here](https://catchts.com/mutations)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using overloads, so you don't need the conditional type for the actual definition. The definition actually doesn't impact the external signature (signature as it appears to userland), so you can actually type things however you want:

```
export function reduce<T, A>(
  values: T[],
  callback: (value1: T | A, value2: T) => T | A,
  accumulator?: A
) {
```

Also something peculiar, using `!== undefined` results in `T & ({} | null)`, but using `typeof` to check instead results in the expected `T`. As for why this is the case, this is [far beyond me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73755224/checking-an-optional-generic-parameter-for-undefined-results-in-t-null).

```
let currentValue = (
  typeof accumulator !== "undefined" ? accumulator : values[0]
)
```

Key take-away: when you use overloads you don't have to make the function definition behave the same as the overloads. It just has to "combine" them all.

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/m3XMLW)