# Checking an optional generic parameter for undefined results in T & ({} | null)

Tags: typescript

So I was answering this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73753461/typed-reduce-function) just now, and in it I found something strange that I could not find explanations of.

If we have a generic function, and the parameter is optional and the parameter's type is using the generic, something like this:

```
function ok<T>(thing?: T) {

}
```

Then when we try to narrow `thing` inside the function to just `T` explicitly checking if it is undefined:

```
thing !== undefined ? thing : 0;
//                    ^? T & ({} | null)
```

Then `thing` is narrowed to `T & ({} | null)`. Moreover, when we use `typeof`, this is narrowed to the expected `T`. This also behaves the same with if statements.

```
typeof thing !== "undefined" ? thing : 0;
//                             ^? T
```

Here's a [minimal reproducible example](https://tsplay.dev/wXjJ8m) with all the things I mentioned:

```
function ok<T>(thing?: T) {
    thing !== undefined ? thing : 0;
    //                    ^?

    if (thing !== undefined) {
        thing
    //  ^?
    }

    typeof thing !== "undefined" ? thing : 0;
    //                             ^?

    if (typeof thing !== "undefined") {
        thing
    //  ^?
    }
}
```

Why is this the case? Do the two conditions actually have different behavior that I didn't know about? Is this a bug? I'm looking for an explanation for this behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the result of [improved intersection reduction, union compatibility, and narrowing](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-8/#improved-intersection-reduction-union-compatibility-and-narrowing), as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#49119](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/49119) and released in TypeScript 4.8.

Certain type guards will now narrow formerly un-narrowable (is that a word?) types by intersecting them with a filtered version of `{} | null | undefined`, a union type equivalent to [the `unknown` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#unknown) because the empty object type `{}` accepts all values *except* `null` and `undefined` (see [How to undestand relations between types any, unknown, {} and between them and other types?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59135229/2887218) for more info).

Specifically, the PR mentions:

> - In control flow analysis of equality comparisons with `null` or `undefined`, generic types are intersected with `{}`, `{} | null`, or `{} | undefined` in the false branch.

In your case, the value `thing` started off as type `T | undefined`, and once you eliminate `undefined` from that with an equality check, you get `T & ({} | null)` which more accurately represents the fact that `thing` cannot be `undefined` than `T` alone would.  While inference would usually prevent this for your exact example, nothing stops someone from writing `ok<string | undefined>(Math.random()<0.5 ? "abc" : undefined)`, and so the type `T` would be `string | undefined` whereas `T & ({} | null)` is just `string` (*not* `string & {}`; see the PR for details about why and how this is different).

On the other hand, this logic was not implemented for the conceptually equivalent `typeof thing !== "undefined"` check.  The only `typeof` check I see being affected here is for `typeof xxx === "object"`.  Whether or not they would consider the difference in narrowing between `x === undefined` and `typeof x === "undefined"` to be a bug, design limitation, intentional, or a missing feature isn't documented there, but TypeScript is definitely behaving as designed.  Maybe it would be worthwhile to open a new issue or at least [comment about it in GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/49119#issuecomment-1250118853)?  Not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Very interesting questions.

I think the reason is something like this:

- according to [this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36124#issuecomment-573145332) when using an unconstrained generic `T` could match both

  - `null` and
  - `{}`
- this will lead you do have a type similar to `T | null | {}`.
- from this it makes sense that when doing `T !== undefined` to end up with something similar to `T & ({} | null)`.
- but when doing a `typeof` to get different results

Also. You can check 2 different things

- Add a constraint to the generic. Something like this `function ok<T extends string>`. This will lead to consistent [results](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=30#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABHA1gHgCqIKYA8rZgAmAzoiVAE4xgDmAfABRQAWNtA-AFyIYCUiAN4BYAFCIJiVu0QBCALzzE4ItmA1sRRByls6iHgAYA3GMmIA9BfM3bdxAD0OYs5JjBEzPbTmLlxNQ0iARFxO2k6VwkrCScoxABfFzCJKABPAAdsOA8InwUlACIVQLBNQu1dGSNTFMtre0amx2dRePdPdKycqv0CxGKA9TKiQpD48zz4mJb4pNF5oA).
- Or use `!=` instead of `!==` which will turn `thing` in `NonNullable<T>`. As it can be seen [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABHA1gHgCoD4AUUAWMYA5gPwBciGAlIgN4CwAUIq4gUcYgIQC8i4ACYBTYEWGDEpdoRKJKABgDczNogD06tdp27EAPVLNVbGMER5ZXPgLAixYCbUYtdHEidabWhz4gC+xq6sUACeAA7CcObu1rz8AERCouKCCVIynPKIyn7eegWFBkZMfmYWYZHRmXJ8ickOEgnOfmqxeVrFfoFMPUA)

It seems like a long, long time ago `{}` was the [top type for generics](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44520#issuecomment-857886424) and changing it now would break a lot of existing code.

Comment: `{}` is no longer the top type for generics; they've been using `unknown` [since TS3.5](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes#generic-type-parameters-are-implicitly-constrained-to-unknown)... and [just in TS4.8](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-8/#unconstrained-generics-no-longer-assignable-to) changed things so that unconstrained generics are no longer assignable to `{}`.