# object possibly `null` when its type is `A | undefined` and we know it can't be `undefined`

Tags: typescript

Starting with version 4.8.4 the TypeScript compiler complains with the following code:

```
type A = {v: number}

function get_the_first<T>(xs: T[]): T | undefined {
    if (xs.length > 1)
        return xs[0];
    else
        return undefined
}

function foo<T>(xs: T[], fielddb: keyof T) {

    let a: T | undefined = get_the_first(xs);

    if (a === undefined) {

    } else {
        console.log(a[fielddb]); // Error: Object is possibly 'null'  
    }

}

foo([{v: 42}], 'v')
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeA3AXFAdgVwLYCMIAnAXwCgyAzbTAY2AEsB7TKAcwmAH1gALCLpQZEAzsAA8AFQB8ACgAeIjJIDaAXQCUyqAB8oNACYQhmCAeRkGlKApEA6ADYRMbPlGlQAjBrJQoRTmwiVkUVAAY1AG4yCAcRaCRff0Dg-UwjEzMycnIqGnpmVkomJik5RWV1ABooIViDA3wMAGsIECZrSQ0LJKdgKABDbT1DYwZTc0QObj4BIVFgWw1opKsbAYR4RFHMg27EpJIoWPiLPz9aFhEmJ0cmNlkBlTqHBvxNSKgAei+oAFEiEQmEQMAB5fAAKwg9CgDBEUDATBEIgY+AcICgAHIcA4HJjDhRcsUmLIVKgMAAWABMJDUNUxKExGiAA)

I don't see why I get this message, variable `a` is either `T` or `undefined` and we've already established that it can't be `undefined`.

Unless it be that the compiler takes the view that the generic type `T` may be the `null` type. If so, how to address this warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`T` type parameter does not have any constraints, so it can be anything, which can be basically represented as:

```
type T = {} | null | undefined
```

You've eliminated `undefined`, but not `null`. That's what TypeScript is saying.

Instead, you could change the condition to:

```
if (a == null) {
```

… which (if you are strictly against `==` operator) is exactly equal to:

```
if (a === null || a === undefined) {
```

*[Try it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.4&ssl=23&ssc=20&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeA3AXFAdgVwLYCMIAnAXwCgyAzbTAY2AEsB7TKAcwmAH1gALCLpQZEAzsAA8AFQB8ACgAeIjJIDaAXQCUyqAB8oNACYQhmCAeRkGlKApEA6ADYRMbPlGlQAjBrJQoRTmwiVkUVAAY1AG4yCAcRaCRff0Dg-UwjEzMycnIqGnpmVkomJik5RWV1ABooIViDA3wMAGsIECZrSQ0LJKdgKABDbT1DYwZTc0QObj4BIVFgWw1opKsbAYREHAcHbsSkkihY+Is-P1oWESYnRyY2WQGVOocG-E1IqAB6T6gAUSIiEwiBgAPL4ABWEHoUAYIigYCYIhEDHwDhAUAA5NsHBiDhRcsUmLIVKgMAAWABMJDUNQxKAxGiAA).*

Comment: ok, so I've confirmed that changing, in the generic function definition `<T>` to `<T extends {}>` fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct that the compiler sees that if `T` includes `null`, then `a` could potentially be `null` since you only check for `undefined`. However, it's a simple fix; just check for null, too:

```
if (a === undefined || a === null) {

} else {
    console.log(a[fielddb]);
}
```

Some people like to shorten this to

```
if (a == null) {
```

But I like to keep it explicit and not rely on JavaScript's unpredictable behavior.

See jcalz's answer here: [Checking an optional generic parameter for undefined results in T & ({} | null)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73755224/checking-an-optional-generic-parameter-for-undefined-results-in-t-null)

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeA3AXFAdgVwLYCMIAnAXwCgyAzbTAY2AEsB7TKAcwmAH1gALCLpQZEAzsAA8AFQB8ACgAeIjJIDaAXQCUyqAB8oNACYQhmCAeRkGlKApEA6ADYRMbPlGlQAjBrJQoRTmwiVkUVAAY1AG4yCAcRaCRff0Dg-UwjEzMycnIqGnpmVkomJik5RWV1ABooIViDA3wMAGsIECZrSQ0LJKdgKABDbT1DYwZTc0QObj4BIVFgWw1opKsbAYR4RFHM8x09Da3EHAcHbsSkkihY+Is-P1oWESYnRyY2WQGVOocG-E1on5crlikxZCpUBgACwAJhIahqAHIUIiNEA)

Answer (score 0):

You could take any approach from the answers above, as there is no single correct solution for this problem.

The approach I would take here is to add a constraint to the generic like this:

```
function foo<T extends Bar>(xs: T[], fielddb: keyof T) { ... }
```

Where `Bar` is the object of the shape(s) you expect it to be.